# Sorting table rows of the current page with quasar

Tags: sorting, quasar

I have a paginated `q-table` in quasar, and I'm trying to sort it's columns. However, it sorts
the whole table. Is there any way to make it sort only the current page?

Comment: You can trick `q-table` into server-side mode - and then feed it only with the data for the current page. Then it will sort only the current page - but you will have to handle the page navigation.

Comment: I tried to use this example  [link](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#server-side-pagination-filter-and-sorting) but same issue it sorts the whole table.

Comment: Because you are feeding the whole table to `q-table`. In server-side mode you should feed only the current page to `q-table` - not the whole amount of data.

Comment: Exactly! i didn't pay attention to the data i'm feeding to sort function, thank you so much!